# enumerate JSON properties in C# DalSoft.RestClient and/or Json.net

Tags: c#, json, rest, nuget-package, dalsoft.restclient

Trying to get this to work in a console app for a simple example. 
I'm using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and [DalSoft.RestClient](https://github.com/DalSoft/DalSoft.RestClient) packages from nuget. I'm not married to either one of these I'm just trying to get the job done. Open to an alternative.

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users returns valid JSON.

I want to enumerate the properties that are unknown in advance.  The following seemed viable but fails with a *System.AggregateException - RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference* I feel like I have missed something simple.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DalSoft.RestClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ImTired
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoThingsAsync().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task<object> DoThingsAsync()
        {
            dynamic client = new RestClient("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
            var user = await client.Users.Get();
            var foo = user[0].name; // grab the first item (Works to this point)

            //JProperty item = new JProperty(user);
            var item = user[0];

            foreach (JProperty property in item.Properties()) //(fails here I've missed a cast or conversion)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " - " + property.Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Call Complete: " + foo);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Solution Explorer view for version ref]

---

**Follow up EDIT:** Added this for any lurkers. *I needed* to add the assemblies to the GAC to make it available for a [scripting tool](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator). This for your Strong Name information.

I understand that there is probably another, better, way to reference a non GAC'd assembly.  I just don't have time to figure it out. Maybe I'll form a meaningful question here.

Interesting results:
[image]

Comment: Should `item.Properties()` be `item.properties()` or `item.properties`?  The error makes it sounds like `.Properties()` is the wrong thing to call because that would be how you create a new instance of a class, not how you access a property or method.

Comment: What is the actual type of `item` as returned by `item.GetType().FullName`?  And what is the declared type returned by `client.Users.Get()`?  Finally, what is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DalSoft Rest Client does not expose JsObject/JsArray.It wraps JSON inside RestClientResponseObject and exposes as a string with ToString method.To get all JSON properties, we need to parse explicitly string to JObject/JArray.

```
var item =JObject.Parse(user[0].ToString());
OR  
var users = JArray.Parse(user.ToString());
var item = users[0];
```

Comment: This is a great explanation of WHY it was not working and how to fix it. The WHY is the reason I give the answer credit here. Although vanderlei provided a fully working answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (I used RestSharp):

```
 using System;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
 using RestSharp;

 namespace ImNotSoTired
 {
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             DoThingsAsync().Wait();
             Console.ReadLine();
         }

         private static async Task<object> DoThingsAsync()
         {
             RestClient client = new RestClient("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
             var response = client.Execute(new RestRequest("users"));

             JArray users = JArray.Parse(response.Content);
             var user = (JObject)users[0];

             foreach (JProperty property in user.Properties())
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " - " + property.Value);
             }

             return null;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this working answer. +1!  I struggled about who to give the answer credit to.  I will however be switching to RestSharp as it looks to be a more mature product.  Please keep up the good work providing quality answers. The community appreciates you.

Comment: @JoeJohnston They solve different problems, my RestClient gives you full control of the pipeline using handlers and allows you cast to static types in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

DalSoft.RestClient returns either a dynamic object or you can cast it to a class. There are examples of this in documentation let me know if anything is missing.

Also ask anything you like on the gitter channel.

Below is your code working. If you need to return the property name then you have to cast to a static type first, and use refection as normal.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DalSoft.RestClient;

namespace ImTired
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DoThingsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task<object> DoThingsAsync()
        {
            dynamic client = new RestClient("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
            List<User> users = await client.Users.Get();
            var foo = users[0].name; // grab the first item (Works to this point)

            var user = users[0]; 
            foreach (var propertyInfo in user.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name + " - " + propertyInfo.GetValue(user));
            }

            return null;
        }        
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string website { get; set; }
    }
}
```